# Is it possible to pass the one-panel data to another panel query label value? - Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-loki, grafana-api

I have created a panel to find out the canary instances(Blue/Green) and it shows the usage of those instances with IP address. Now I need to create another panel to show the errors of that instance(will grep certain words in the log) with the help of LOKI and it's a different data source. The issue is it doesn't have a canary label only ipaddress label there so I must pass the ipaddress in that query. But I don't know how to filter the ipaddress of the canary instances and pass it on to that query.

Is it possible to pass the one-panel data to another panel query label value?

Answer (score 0):

You can [share query result](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/panels/query-a-data-source/share-query/), but that's solution not for your use case. Create hidden dashboard variable, where you will prepare variable (e.g. IP) based on another variable (e.g. canary instance name) and use that additional variable in your Loki query.